# как приравнять значения аттрибута value в невыбранном еще option

Tags: html-select

```
<select class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Choose SCategory" name="scategory_id" title="Deal_SCategory">
                 <option label="Choose category"></option>
                          @foreach($scategories as $item)
                 <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->scategory_name}}</option>
                          @endforeach
        </select>
```

Comment: на js  вот что у меня: selectedValueSession = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedValue');
       selectedTextSession = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedText');
 $('select[name="scategory_id"]').append('<option selected value="'+selectedValue+'">'+selectedText+'</option>');

Comment: В результате должно быть выделен OPTION , и он ВЫДЕЛЕН сразу при загрузке , но ДУБЛИКАТ .... и мне надо его УБРАТЬ, то есть граммотно ПРИРАВНЯТЬ значения из СЕССИИ и  <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->scategory_name}}</option>    - из верстки